# How to buid a LMS (Learning Management System) using joomla?

Tags: components, joomla1.7

I want to build a LMS (learning management system) using joomla. I am not aware of the complexity that it takes into. I am looking for step by step **guidance** on how to get started this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a question that can be answered without a lot more details. This is the same as asking someone how to write a good book.

Look at this Joomla based LMS for some ideas - http://www.joomlalms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think I would state the question as how to build web apps with Joomla.. then specifically go towards the lms.. Joomla can be used as an application development platform and you can easily extend it by writing custom extensions..

You can look at the Joomla docs on how to to get started with this.. Once you know how to develop Joomla extensions you can use it to built as any kind of a web application or even a backend for mobile apps..

You can also choose to start from an existing extension that does LMS and extend it as it would save you a lot of time.. our company develops Shika which is a feature rich LMS for Joomla..

You can find out more here 
https://techjoomla.com/products/shika.html

Regards